# IIS showing directory instead of index.php and gives 404 when i click a file

Tags: iis

im new to IIS and am having a few issues with it.

ive uploaded wordpress on a site just to test the site and see if i can get it connected with mysql.

when i go on the site: [www.uacdn.info](http://www.uacdn.info), it shows a directory of files, even though i have added index.php to the default page, and when i click a file in that directory it gives me a 404 error..

what have i done or not done wrong?

ive tried restarting the website via IIS and adding index.php to the default page and in 1st position.

Comment: That simply indicates you didn't configure PHP on IIS properly. What did you configure exactly? It is very important that you follow 1.3 on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php#13-download-and-install-php-manually

Comment: Usually, If directory browsing is enabled and no default document is specified the client will recive directory of files, but you have set the default document, can you post details about 404 error?